# What is result of failed numeric type evaluation in javax.xml.xpath

Tags: java, xpath

The documentation of javax.xml.xpath is astonishingly thin:
For example, the method [evaluate(String expression, Object item, QName returnType)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.InputSource,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29) lists the various exceptions thrown as follows:

> Throws:
>
> ```
> XPathExpressionException - If expression cannot be evaluated.
>
> IllegalArgumentException - If returnType is not one of the types defined in XPathConstants.
>
> NullPointerException - If expression, source or returnType is null.
> ```

Now consider the case when the `returnType` parameter is `XPathConstants.NUMBER`, which is supposed to return an Object of type `java.lang.Double`.  What if xml expression selected with this call is something like

```
<NUMBER_OF_PAGES>garbage</NUMBER_OF_PAGES>
```

Will this call throw an XpathExpressionException, or will it return with a value such as NaN?  This is undocumented.  The Javadocs are filled with links to the XPath specification, etc., but this obvious question isn't answered there.

Yes, I know I could experiment and just see what it does, but I shouldn't have to dig back into specs to have this question answered.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it for you. The result will still be `Double` if you specify return type as `XPathConstants.NUMBER`. But it shows up as `NaN`.
If you specify `XPathConstants.NODE`, it will return you empty nodelist.

Comment: Thanks.  Still would like to know why the javadoc is so sparse about this.